# How do I make images interactive?

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring-mvc, responsive-design

So I am trying to make an interactive seating chart for a client.
This is the image that I am trying to use.
http://imgh.us/New_Seat_map_1.svg

How would I make the seats in the image interactive. For example when you choose a seat it will change colors etc. Also I need it to be able to connect to a database so when the page loads it has the available seats and unavailable seats displayed.

Im not sure where to even start on a task like this. My current back-end is MySQL and Spring MVC. Any tips? Im guessing I can do it with CSS and javascript but not sure.

Comment: So what's the *actual question*?

Comment: I'm trying to make the seats in the image interactive. So if you choose a seat, it changes the color of that seat and changes the value to "selected".

Comment: I still don't see an 'actual question'. We don't write code for you. Please attempt something yourself and come back with a specific question

Comment: I said "Im not sure where to even start on a task like this" lol im not sure how I would even make certain parts of an img clickable.

Comment: Then learn and come back with a specific question. This is unclear and broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inline SVG. Like this... http://bl.ocks.org/widged/4545199.